# Keep changing view by using forever-loop in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

I am trying to make a textview change each second by writing a forever-loop in AsyncTask, but the apps doesn't run successfully and I do not know the reason:

```
private class BackGround extends  AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {  
        while(true){    
             textview.setText("abc");
             try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             textview.setText("def");
             try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }       
}
```

It works fine until the thread finishes the first sleep and tries to reset the textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do UI things from `doInBackground`.  You should try calling `publishProgress(...)` in your while loop to do the UI updates.  This will cause `onProgressPublished` to be called, in which you can actually make the changes.

```
private class BackGround extends  AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {  
        while(true){    
             publishProgress( "abc" );
             try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             publishProgress( "def" );
             try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }  

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate( String ...progress ){
        textView.setText( progress[0] );
    }
}
```

Comment: The generic parameters should be `AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>`

Comment: It's a good advice but this code require further inprovement. Endless loop will probably create memory leak. If it is  an inner class of activity it will hold a reference to activity and not allow clear activity from memory. Next launch of activity will create new background task and so on. Instead while(true) there should be while(isCancelled) and reference to asynctask should be cancel when activity is destroyed.